# How can I produce a valid Private Key (in any format) from the primes?

Tags: cryptography, rsa

I have the necessary components to build the private/public RSA key: N, E, D, P, & Q.  I can derive the other values for the CRT if needed.  How can I use these parameters to produce a valid Private/Public key in DER, PEM, or PKCS#7? It doesn't matter which to me as I can convert between them.  I'm looking for a tool, library, script, or program that supports assigning these values and writing out a valid file, so I don't have to read hundreds of pages on ASN.1.  Every tool I've looked at doesn't expose this use case in the API.

Comment: According to Area 51, questions about library usage are offtopic in crypto.se

Comment: What language? Java, C, python ... It matters.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java, there is the [`RSAPrivateKeySpec`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/security/spec/RSAPrivateKeySpec.html) class, which takes `BigInteger` arguments of modulus and exponent. There are subclasses which take instead of N the P and Q primes (for more efficiency). You can then use a [KeyFactory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/security/KeyFactory.html) to convert this object to a Key, and then to some EncodedKeySpec class like  [PKCS8EncodedKeySpec](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/security/spec/PKCS8EncodedKeySpec.html) or [X509EncodedKeySpec](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/security/spec/X509EncodedKeySpec.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use OpenSSL (the library).

BIGNUM is described [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/bn.html#). There are many functions to create a BIGNUM out of your input (depending on format). `BN_bin2bn` is probably the simplest, but hexadecimal or decimal input is also supported.

RSA is a structure that contains BIGNUMs. It's described [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/rsa.html#). You can initialise it yourself (directly).

You can then write the RSA structure using one of the PEM functions (described [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/pem.html#)). For example, `PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey` writes a PEM file containing a private key (you can also encrypt it, if you want to).

I'm not aware of any tool that does all of the above. Also, ASN.1 isn't so bad (a public/private key is pretty much a SEQUENCE of INTEGERs).